# Integer conversions in Rust

Tags: rust

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67620c5e1ce288f7ed0ffdefea9bcf68

```
fn main() {
    let a: usize = 100;
    let b: u32 = 100;
    let z: i32 = a*b;
}
```

How do I tell the compiler which type I want there?

Comment: what do you mean with: ***which type I want there?***.... z is a i32, that is what you want isnt??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ what? I don't understand your english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I tell the compiler which type I want there?

You cast the variable to proper type. For example if you want to do the multiplication as `i32` type, you would:

```
let z: i32 = (a as i32) * (b as i32);
```

More about casting is available in [Rust manual - Casting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/cast.html).

Comment: Thank you. Why does the compiler suggest `try_into()` if this is simpler?

Comment: Because conversions with `as` may panic (in debug mode) or cause wrong results (in release mode) if the inputs don't fit in the requested type.